# Is there a word for words that represent letters?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the category of words that represent alphabet characters? e.g. zee, bee, see, es, etc. This is required for purposes of textual banter.

Comment: Phonetic transcription: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_transcription - Phonemic orthography: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonemic_orthography

Comment: If it's banter, you could invent a word like: alphanym or lexiconym

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a word for indicating alphabet letters, specifically; However, such words definitely fall under the onomatopoeia category of words.

**onomatopoeia**

```
  : the creation of words that imitate natural sounds*
```

1:  the naming of a thing or action by a vocal imitation of the sound associated with it (as buzz, hiss)

2:  the use of words whose sound suggests the sense

— on·o·mato·poe·ic -ˈpē-ik\ or on·o·mato·po·et·ic -pō-ˈe-tik\ adjective
— on·o·mato·poe·i·cal·ly -ˈpē-ə-k(ə-)lē\ or on·o·mato·po·et·i·cal·ly -pō-ˈe-ti-k(ə-)lē\ adverb